# SimpleSpriteSequence and getRandom

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an Gameobject that contains several prefabs, As in the picture below
[image]

```
public SimpleSpriteSequence birds;
Randomizer setBirds;
setBirds = new Randomizer(birds.sprites);
    int index = setBirds.getRandom();
    birds.setCurrentSpriteIndex(index);
```

In the image below we see the population of the array
[image]

```
Invoke("Interface", 1f);
```

Now with the help of the random I get a random bird from the array. But the problem is that the bird can be repeated. All I want is that at least 6 times in a row when the Invoke("Interface", 1f); function does not repeat the bird.So in principle I have to do so 6 times the bird does not repeat itself. To be a random of these birds but 6 times to be different birds. No I know if I explained it properly, but I hope you understand the idea.

Comment: So you want first bird to be able to repeat only after 5 other random birds are spawned?

Comment: Yeah, like that

Comment: @George if you find a solution, be sure to accept the answer. I see that all your previous questions are left without an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code but it is written in console application since i do not have your code and it is writen with custom class of `Birds` but you will adapt it to your code. If you need help with it i will help you.

```
class Birds
{
    public int birdID;
    public string birdName;
    //public Sprite birdSprite;
}
class Program
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    static Birds[] birds = new Birds[10];
    static int nBirdsSpawned = 0;
    static List<int> spawnedBirds = new List<int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Database of my birds ;)
        birds[0] = new Birds();
        birds[1] = new Birds();
        birds[2] = new Birds();
        birds[3] = new Birds();
        birds[4] = new Birds();
        birds[5] = new Birds();
        birds[6] = new Birds();
        birds[7] = new Birds();
        birds[8] = new Birds();
        birds[9] = new Birds();
        birds[0].birdID = 0;
        birds[0].birdName = "Bird 1";
        birds[1].birdID = 1;
        birds[1].birdName = "Bird 2";
        birds[2].birdID = 2;
        birds[2].birdName = "Bird 3";
        birds[3].birdID = 3;
        birds[3].birdName = "Bird 4";
        birds[4].birdID = 4;
        birds[4].birdName = "Bird 5";
        birds[5].birdID = 5;
        birds[5].birdName = "Bird 6";
        birds[6].birdID = 6;
        birds[6].birdName = "Bird 7";
        birds[7].birdID = 7;
        birds[7].birdName = "Bird 8";
        birds[8].birdID = 8;
        birds[8].birdName = "Bird 9";
        birds[9].birdID = 9;
        birds[9].birdName = "Bird 10";

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 100)
        {
            RandomSpawn();
            i++;
        }

        Console.Write("Finished");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void CheckForBirdSpawn(int birdID)
    {
        if (nBirdsSpawned <= 6)
        {
            if (!spawnedBirds.Contains(birdID))
            {
                spawnedBirds.Add(birdID);
                SpawnBird(birdID);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bird " + birds[birdID].birdName + " is already spawned!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SpawnBird(birdID);
        }
    }

    static void SpawnBird(int birdID)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(birds[birdID].birdName);
        nBirdsSpawned++;
    }

    static void RandomSpawn()
    {
        int r = rnd.Next(0, 10);

        CheckForBirdSpawn(r);
    }
}
```

Until first 6 birds are spawned it check if bird is already spawned and if it is it doesn't allow it's spawning. After 6 birds are spawned it allows every bird to be spawned.

Here is output in console app:

[image]

Comment: Ok, now I'm trying

Comment: I want to ask you
index = birdYouWantToSpawnID?

Comment: Does not make random birds

Comment: So he does nothing, he is the first bird and so

Comment: Well try to explain otherwise, maybe you did not understand the idea

Comment: index = 3 => Invoke => index = 1 => Invoke => index = 9 => Invoke => index = 5 => Invoke => index = 7 => Invoke => index = 2 => Invoke

Comment: And so every time, just as the index changes

Comment: But it is not repeated

Comment: At least 6 times not to repeat

Comment: I edited my answer but i have to ask you something. After 5 spawning of random birds 6th spawn `you want to spawn first bird` or `you want to make it possible to spawn same bird as already spawned 5 spawning ago`

Comment: So the first 6 birds will always be different.After 6 different birds appeared, it does not matter anymore

Comment: so lets say this is order of spawning birds:
(ids) 1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7 and after this bird 6 could be spawned or just 1?

Comment: Yes, after that he can no longer do random

Comment: So the idea is that six times different birds, then it can do any random

Comment: You have my edited answer and it is tested. If there is problem about adapting it to your code just ask me and i will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a mainly code reply but how about you try something a little like this?

1. Populate a list of the bird indexes.
2. Pick a random index within that list.
3. Decrease all already spawned birds' Values.
4. If any reach zero, re-add the birds index into the availableBird list.
5. Spawn the bird, while adding it's index as Key and the amount of spawning delay needed until it can be spawned again as the Value.
6. Remove the birds index from the list.

Do the spawn whenever necessary, this will spawn every frame since it is found in a Coroutine which has an infinite while loop.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class burd : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool spawning;
    private System.Random rnd = new System.Random();

    private Dictionary<int, int> spawnedBurdies = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    private List<int> availableBurdies = new List<int>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        {
            availableBurdies.Add(index);
        }
        StartCoroutine(SpawnBurdies());
    }

    private IEnumerator SpawnBurdies()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (spawning)
            {
                int burdIndex = rnd.Next(availableBurdies.Count);
                spawnBurd(availableBurdies[burdIndex]);
                availableBurdies.RemoveAt(burdIndex);
            }
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }
    }

    private void spawnBurd(int burdIndex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Spawned burd #" + burdIndex);
        List<int> burdieKeys = new List<int>();

        foreach (var burdie in spawnedBurdies) { burdieKeys.Add(burdie.Key); }

        foreach (var burdieKey in burdieKeys)
        {
            spawnedBurdies[burdieKey]--;
            if(spawnedBurdies[burdieKey] <= 0)
            {
                spawnedBurdies.Remove(burdieKey);
                availableBurdies.Add(burdieKey);
            }
        }

        spawnedBurdies.Add(burdIndex, 6);
    }
}
```

This solution would save you from attempting to spawn birds that can't be spawned; but if there are less birds than the minimum spawns to wait for, an Argument out of range error would be thrown.

Comment: Hello, I have not tested yet. I'm not at work now, but I'm trying to test now.

Comment: @George Okay, well, once you have tested please be sure to accept the answer that suited your needs best/helped you out the most. I saw that none of your previous questions had an accepted answer. Hopefully this will work for you.